# iOS performance when using big glyph icons (images) that rescales for all resolutions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, png

I'm developing a new app that will be universal (iPhone 3.5" & 4" and iPads).

I've downloaded a free set of png icons.
I've notice that due to their plain glyph style a 512X512 px icons
only takes 5kb.

Is it a good idea to import and use only the high resolution icons
and rescale them if need (for all devices)? will it cause performance issues or such? 
(extreme case rescaling 515X512 to 30X30)

(When i say rescaling i mean let the uiimageview/ uibutton to handle it).

Other thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a very bad idea.

The images are probably in a vector format (like EPS or Illustrator files). Those tend to be pretty small, and scale beautifully. However, they're not supported by iOS. For iOS, you have to convert to a raster format. No matter what format they are in, they get converted to RGBA pixels when you load them into memory, and take 4 bytes per pixels. a 512x512 pixel image will take 512x512x4 bytes, or 1,048,576 bytes. That's over a megabyte per image.

Scaling takes a lot of memory and is slow. The system has to keep the larger image in memory AND the smaller image, and apply a time-consuming scaling operation each time it wants to draw the image.

You should scale your images to your target size, and save them as PNGs. iOS is optimized for PNGs, and PNGs can include an alpha channel, while JPEG images do not. You should include both 1X and @2x retina images, assuming you will run on iPad as well as iPhone. (There are no non-retina iPhones that run iOS 7)